# Define height and width of iFrame in PhoneGap app on iOS

Tags: iphone, css, ios, cordova

We're having trouble setting the height and width on an iFrame in a PhoneGap app on iOS.

We set the values in CSS and inline on the iFrame element itself. Both fail to control the dimensions of the iFrame.

Is this possible?

We're on PhoneGap 1.2.

Comment: maybe try setting display:block

Comment: Do you have the iframe domain added to your whitelist?

Comment: is OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set to YES?

Comment: What are the dimensions regardless of the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using device-pixel-ratio to set correct values help you.

For retina displays device-pixel-ratio = 2, and 1.5 for other.

Use this ratio in css with media query:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0), only screen and (device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) {
/* your css */
}
```

And in JavaScript:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
```